# ¿Cómo almacenar en una lista el parámetro de un método List en Java?

Tags: java, lista, método

Tengo un error al almacenar en una lista los nombres de los archivos de un directorio, me aparece vacio.

> List a = getFiles(paths);

A continuación el código:

```
public class TransferProyect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //String path = "/usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/";
        String paths = "/usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/old_version/";

        List a = getFiles(paths);   

        System.out.println("Files: "+a);

    }

    public static List<Object>  getFiles(String path) {
        List <Object> FilterProyect = new ArrayList<>();
        File f = new File(path);
        if(f.isDirectory()){
            File [] proyect = f.listFiles(filtrados);
            int size = proyect.length;
            for(int cont=0; cont<size;cont++){

                System.out.println(proyect[cont]);
            }
        }else{System.out.println("Don't is Directory...");}

        return FilterProyect;
    }

}
```

Comment: `List<Object>` no tiene sentido, es lo mismo que `List`, es un mal uso de genéricos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error más grave que veo en tu código está en que como verás nunca guardas los directorios que obtienes, solamente los imprimes en consola.

Deberías de usar el método `add` de List para guardarle cosas a esa estructura de datos.

```
public static List<Object>  getFiles(String path) {
            List <Object> FilterProyect = new ArrayList<>();
           // si sale bien o sale mal solamente imprimes a consola
          return FilterProyect;
}
```

Te dejo la documentación oficial sobre el método y la clase: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-

Answer (score 2):

Además de usar el método `add`, debes tener en cuenta que para imprimir un `List` debes recorrer sus elementos para ir iterando por ellos e imprimir de uno en uno, de lo contrario lo que obtienes es un `String` que representan el objeto pero no son elementos.

```
System.out.println("Files: ");
for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(a.get(i));
}
```

Asi debe imprimir lo que quieres.